# Calling javascript function from php with array php arguments

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a javascript function named `table()` in a seperate file called "table.js".
It basically gets 3 array arguments and sorts them, then fills the HTML table with sorted values.

The problem is:
3 array arguments are in PHP and they are PHP array variables.
How can I:
Call the table function with these php array variables like:

```
table($name,$grade,$grade2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply like this:

```
<script>

var name = [<?php echo '"' . implode('","', $name) . '"'; ?>];
var grade1 = [<?php echo '"' . implode('","', $grade1) . '"'; ?>];
var grade2 = [<?php echo '"' . implode('","', $grade2) . '"'; ?>];

table(name, grade1, grade2);

</script>
```

Comment: And what should my javascript function be? It is currently like: function table(name,grade1,grade2) Is it okay?

Comment: @user3179249 that should be okay, yes.

Comment: @user3179249 see my updated answer, please. I just realized you can't just `echo` an array, plus arrays in PHP look a bit different from arrays in JS. The code in my updated answer should work though.

Comment: Alright, and i added <script src="table.js"></script> to the start of the <body> of the HTML. So if i call the function within the php, it will be same as manually writing the arrays on top of javascript code like: names=["adam","daniel] grades1=[50,100] right?

Comment: @user3179249 For example `<?php echo json_encode($name); ?>` will become: `['adam', 'daniel']`.

Comment: @user3179249 did it work for you? I just updated the code in my answer. The code should be better working now.

Comment: Actually i just figured my java code does not work. I am trying to solve it. It was working before but i had to change it and make it a function. Earlier, it was not a function. I manually entered arrays at the start of the code to test the sort algorithm. It worked earlier. It was like: names=["adam","daniel]; grades1=[50,100]; and the rest is sort algorithm. But now i had to make it a function table(names,grades) and call it like table(["adam","daniel],[50,100]) but it dont set names=["adam","daniel]; grades1=[50,100]; for some reason.

Comment: @user3179249 hmm.. well if you get stuck with that just start a new question. I would gladely help with that too :).

Answer (score 1):

```
 var name = "<?php echo $name; ?>";
 var grade1= "<?php echo $grade1; ?>";
 var grade2= "<?php echo $grade2; ?>";


table(name,grade1,grade2);
```